# Android compose, scale in image without cropping?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I would like this image to 'scale in' to the app, but without being cropped to the original image size.

This works great, just as I want until I put the image within a row, column, box, etc. The below animation is my goal. This works if I only have the image in the layout.

[image: Working - without any container]

The above is drawn with the below code:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant
            )
            {
                Display()
            }
        }
    }

    @Preview
    @Composable
    fun Display()
    {
            ScaleImage()
    }


    @Composable
    fun ScaleImage()
    {
        val vector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.smarter_garage_svg)
        val painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = vector)

        var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        // a best effort 'hack' to avoid jumpiness of having no image in place when the garage image is temporarily hidden, uses this empty background to keep spacing

        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = visible,
            enter = scaleIn(initialScale = 5f, animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 2000)) +
            fadeIn(
                // Fade in with the initial alpha of 0.3f.
                initialAlpha = 0.01f,
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000)
            )
        )
        {
            Image(
                painter = painter,
                contentDescription = "garage",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize(),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
        }
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            delay(1.milliseconds)
            visible = true
        }
    }
```

However, if I try to use any layout, my animated scaled image is cropped to the originating image bounds.

[image]

Which I'm using something like below

```
    @Preview
    @Composable
    fun Display()
    {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(20.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)
        )
        {
            ScaleImage()
        }
    }
```

my SVG is like below

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:viewportWidth="150"
    android:viewportHeight="150">
    <path
        android:name="front"
        android:fillColor="#fb0101"
        android:pathData="M15.002,42.815V137.24H30.739V54.92h89.583v82.319h15.737V42.815l-60.529,-26.196 -1.211,0.034c-59.318,26.162 0,0 -59.318,26.162z"
        android:strokeWidth="1.21061"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" />
    <path
        android:name="door"
        android:fillColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:pathData="M45.266,68.237V137.24H105.795V68.237Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1.21061"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" />
    <path
        android:name="handle"
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M68.712,122.423a7.387,6.945 0,1 0,14.774 0a7.387,6.945 0,1 0,-14.774 0z"
        android:strokeWidth="1.21061" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M1.046,137.248h147.95v10.091h-147.95z"
        android:strokeWidth="1.2144" />
    <path
        android:name="house_frame"
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M74.147,1.105C50.028,12.041 25.909,22.976 1.79,33.911c-1.14,0.677 -0.577,2.167 -0.712,3.248 -0.021,33.178 -0.042,66.356 -0.062,99.534 0.038,1.084 1.218,1.343 2.101,1.206 3.806,-0.044 7.625,0.003 11.424,-0.095 1.206,-0.126 1.13,-1.533 1.083,-2.439 0.021,-30.719 0.042,-61.439 0.062,-92.158 18.706,-8.222 37.37,-16.543 56.107,-24.686 1.087,-0.396 2.134,-1.031 3.278,-1.206 3.935,1.404 7.72,3.204 11.576,4.809 16.248,7.013 32.485,14.053 48.728,21.078 0.019,31.142 0.04,62.283 0.061,93.425 0.038,1.077 1.208,1.34 2.087,1.215 3.47,-0.002 6.951,0.084 10.414,0.026 1.154,-0.098 1.165,-1.434 1.095,-2.315 -0.018,-33.602 -0.041,-67.203 -0.062,-100.805 -0.147,-1.324 -1.745,-1.415 -2.679,-1.978C122.575,22.216 98.857,11.658 75.139,1.101c-0.338,-0.046 -0.666,-0.165 -0.992,0.003z"
        android:strokeWidth="0.126265" />
    <path
        android:name="garage_frame_wrapper"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M45.266,137.24V68.237h60.529v69.003h14.527V54.92H30.739v82.319h14.527"
        android:strokeWidth="1.21061"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt"
        android:strokeLineJoin="miter" />
    <path
        android:name="garage_frame"
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="m30.713,54.916c-0.657,1.202 -0.137,2.713 -0.303,4.042 0,25.895 0,51.789 0,77.683 0.333,1.417 2.134,0.657 3.169,0.848 3.743,-0.041 7.515,0.083 11.24,-0.06 1.213,-0.459 0.479,-2.112 0.68,-3.108 0,-21.921 0,-43.843 0,-65.764 20.031,0 40.063,0 60.094,0 0,22.695 0,45.39 0,68.085 0.333,1.417 2.134,0.657 3.169,0.848 3.743,-0.041 7.515,0.083 11.24,-0.06 1.213,-0.459 0.48,-2.112 0.68,-3.108 0,-26.252 0,-52.503 0,-78.755 -0.332,-1.417 -2.133,-0.657 -3.169,-0.848 -28.752,0 -57.504,0 -86.255,0 -0.182,0.066 -0.363,0.132 -0.545,0.198z"
        android:strokeWidth="0.178596"
        android:strokeColor="#000000" />
</vector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing works unusual in Image with

```
   @Preview
    @Composable
    fun Display()
    {
            ScaleImage()
    }
```

or

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Display()
{
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)
    )
    {
        ScaleImage()
    }
}
```

samples. In first one you don't set a dimension for preview while intrinsic size for vector resouce is 200.dp. In second one you set full width but Image still occupies 200.dp. Easiest way to observe this is adding borders around Image, AnimatedVisibility.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ScaleImage() {
    val vector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_garrage)
    val painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = vector)


    var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    // a best effort 'hack' to avoid jumpiness of having no image in place
    // when the garage image is temporarily hidden, uses this empty background to keep spacing

    AnimatedVisibility(
        modifier = Modifier.border(3.dp, Color.Red),
        visible = visible,
        enter = scaleIn(initialScale = 5f, animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 2000)) +
                fadeIn(
                    // Fade in with the initial alpha of 0.3f.
                    initialAlpha = 0.01f,
                    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000)
                )
    )
    {
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = "garage",
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(6.dp, Color.Blue)
                .wrapContentSize(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        delay(1.milliseconds)
        visible = true
    }
}
```

And with Column one if you add a reference Box with 200.dp you will see that both works as expected

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Display() {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Green),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)
    )
    {
        ScaleImage()

        Box(Modifier.size(200.dp).background(Color.Yellow))
    }
}
```

And to make it scale fullscreen properly you can assign `Modifier.fillMaxSize` before `wrapContentSize`.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ScaleImage() {
    val vector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_garrage)
    val painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = vector)


    var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    // a best effort 'hack' to avoid jumpiness of having no image in place
    // when the garage image is temporarily hidden, uses this empty background to keep spacing

    AnimatedVisibility(
        modifier = Modifier.border(3.dp, Color.Red),
        visible = visible,
        enter = scaleIn(initialScale = 5f, animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 2000)) +
                fadeIn(
                    // Fade in with the initial alpha of 0.3f.
                    initialAlpha = 0.01f,
                    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000)
                )
    )
    {
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = "garage",
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(6.dp, Color.Blue)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .wrapContentSize(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        delay(1.milliseconds)
        visible = true
    }
}
```

Which will be displayed like this with or without Column or any other Composable wrapping around it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @thracian this seems to be the trick. My larger project has more complexities and overlays but this allowed my animation to use the full real estate available and stop cropping at the native size

```
                .fillMaxSize()
                .wrapContentSize(),
```

Comment: You can mark Thracians answer as accepted answer then by clicking the checkmark at the left side of his answer.